# Resource leak while using try...finally?

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, eclipse-juno, java-6

I was working normally in eclipse when I got bugged by a resource leak warning in both `return` values inside the `try` block in this method:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(File file) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            line = line.trim();
            if(line.isEmpty())
                continue;
            if(line.startsWith("#") == false)
                return false;
            if(line.startsWith("#MLProperties"))
                return true;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        try{reader.close();}catch(Exception e){}
    }
    return false;
}
```

I don't understand how it would cause resource leak since I'm declaring the `reader` variable outside the `try` scope, adding a resource inside the `try` block and closing it in a `finally` block using an other `try...catch` to ignore exceptions and a `NullPointerException` if `reader` is `null` for some reason...

From what I know, `finally` blocks are always executed when leaving the `try...catch` structure, so returning a value inside the `try` block would still execute the `finally` block before exiting the method...

This can be easily proved by:

```
public static String test()
{
    String x = "a";
    try
    {
        x = "b";
        System.out.println("try block");
        return x;
    }
    finally
    {
        System.out.println("finally block");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("calling test()");
    String ret = test();
    System.out.println("test() returned "+ret);
}
```

It result in:

```
calling test()
try block
finally block
test() returned b
```

Knowing all this, why is eclipse telling me `Resource leak: 'reader' is not closed at this location` if I'm closing it in my `finally` block?

---

## Answer

I would just add to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15253257/804976) that he's correct, if `new BufferedReader` throws an exception, an instance of `FileReader` would be open upon destruction by garbage collector because it wouldn't be assigned to any variable and the `finally` block would not close it because `reader` would be `null`.

This is how I fixed this possible leak:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(File file) throws IOException
{
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            line = line.trim();
            if(line.isEmpty())
                continue;
            if(line.startsWith("#") == false)
                return false;
            if(line.startsWith("#MLProperties"))
                return true;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        try{reader.close();}catch(Exception e){}
        try{fileReader.close();}catch(Exception ee){}
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Side comment: `if(line.startsWith("#") == false)` is generally written: `if(!line.startsWith("#"))`.

Comment: The warning looks completely spurious.

Comment: In the finally clause, you must check whether reader is not null because if for some reason the reader variable is not instantiated, you will have a NPE.

Comment: Move new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); to the initialization of bufferedreader if it is null it wont try and close

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe it's because your Exception. If there is an IOError while reading, this exception will never catched and your stream is never closed.

Comment: @assylias I know, but I like to use `== false` for easy read. `x == false` and `!x` results in the same bytecode

Comment: The filereader need not to be closed. Closing the BufferedReader will cause the the FileReader to be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `BufferedReader` constructor throws an exception (e.g. out of memory), you will have `FileReader` leaked.

Comment: True that this may cause a leak but the warning isn't there for that reason. Strangely enough, doing this
    FileReader r2 = new FileReader(file);
    reader = new BufferedReader(r2);    remove the warning but doesn't remove the possible leak you pointed out.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Huh... it is just Eclipse.

Comment: Usually it's not worth bothering about `Error`s and things like `IllegalArgumentException`s when cleaning up resource.

Answer (score 4):

There is technically a path for which the BufferedReader would not be closed: if `reader.close()` would throw an exception, because you catch the exception and do nothing with it. This can be verified by adding `reader.close()` again in your catch block:

```
    } finally
    {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            reader.close();
        }
    }
```

Or by removing the try/catch in the finally:

```
    } finally
    {
            reader.close();
    }
```

This will make the warnings disappear.

Of course, it doesn't help you. If reader.close() is failing, then calling it again does not make sense. The thing is, the compiler is not smart enough to handle this. So the only sensible thing you can do is to add a `@SuppressWarnings("resource")` to the method.

**Edit** If you are using Java 7, what you can/should do is using try-with-resources functionality. This will get the warnings right, and makes you code simpler, saving you a `finally` block:

```
public boolean isValid(File file) throws IOException
{
  try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)))
  {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
      line = line.trim();
      if (line.isEmpty())
        continue;
      if (line.startsWith("#") == false)
        return false;
      if (line.startsWith("#MLProperties"))
        return true;
    }
  } 
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you also helped me to understand what was the issue. +1 . I can't use java 7 in this project because I need java 6 compatibility

Answer (score 1):

```
//If this line throws an exception, then neither the try block
    //nor the finally block will execute.
    //That is a good thing, since reader would be null.
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFileName));
    try {
      //Any exception in the try block will cause the finally block to execute
      String line = null;
      while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
        //process the line...
      }
    }
    finally {
      //The reader object will never be null here.
      //This finally is only entered after the try block is 
      //entered. But, it's NOT POSSIBLE to enter the try block 
      //with a null reader object.
      reader.close();
    }
```

Comment: I don't feel safe instantiating a `FileReader` outside a `try` block... I like to always try to close for security reason. I hate when softwares blocks a file by a bug :P

Answer (score 1):

Since `close()` can throw an exception (why oh why did they design it that way...) I tend to use a double try

```
try {
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
  try {
    // do stuff with reader
  } finally {
    reader.close();
  }
} catch(IOException e) {
  // handle exceptions
}
```

Since this idiom eliminates the try/catch within the finally block it may be enough to keep Eclipse happy.

`new BufferedReader(...)` can't itself throw an `IOException` but technically this could still leak the `FileReader` if the `BufferedReader` constructor throws a `RuntimeException` or `Error`.

Comment: how does this answer the question?